# Windows - Why my ram usage is so high ? - Poolmon tested

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory

I have quite a big problem for playing cause I often reach 95% of ram used when I play, even if I have 8Gb in my computer.

What I don't understand is if I open Task Manager and sum everything, I never reach how much used ram it tell me I am using.

For example in this screen, it tells me 48% so around 3.8G used, but if I sum everything I don't even reach 1G.

So can someone explain me what is happening ?

[image: Task Manager]

[image: Resource monitor]

PS: Done check with poolmon and the highest driver show a use of 0.1Gb of ram, so that is not the problem and this is not a duplicate !

PS2 : RamMap say exactly the same as task manager.

Comment: If you want to see what’s using your memory, first try Sysinternals RAMMap.

Comment: Post a screenshot of Task Manager - Performance tab showing memory Info. There are substantial users of memory that are not processes so a sum of process memory usage can never equal the total.

Comment: Here it is, but I don't know what you want to see there http://imgur.com/a/VNRi9

Comment: RAMMap says a lot more than Task Manager. Please provide screenshots of both the “Use Counts” tab and the “Processes” tab, sorted by “Private”.

Comment: here it is : http://imgur.com/a/YpPth

Comment: Done check with poolmon and the highest driver show a use of 0.1Gb of ram, so that is not the problem and this is not a duplicate !

Comment: Finally found how to solve my problem. It seems in some cases Windows let the Windows Search services take a lot, a huge amount of ram. And that never show in Task manager or RamMap. Disabling the windows services now show the right amount of Ram. So as I said, no reason to tag my post as duplicate ... And I can't even answer my own question ...

Comment: You can post your answer to this question now...

Comment: @Alfakyn1 I don't understand why you say that solved your problem. You had no problem before. Now your system is wasting lots of RAM.

Comment: @David Schwartz I had problem. Lag, freeze and slow computer. Not able to use any demanding app (Unity, Visual Studio) or any demanding game. I don't care the ram usage when I'm able to do things without lag. That was not the case, my computer way to tell me, there was a problem.

Comment: @Alfakyn1 Then you asked the wrong question.

Comment: @David Schwartz then you understood the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the solution for me :

I found that sometimes when you have a lot of files Windows allow the "Windows Search" services to become very huge. This result in a very big windows.edb file and in a huge amount of RAM allocated for that.
This part of RAM is used but never shown in Task manager or RamMap.

After disabling the "Windows Search" services my ram usage dropped by 25%.

Comment: Cause when the ram usage is at 95% and that I can't play any games without freeze it shows there is a problem.
Now I don't suffer any lag at all since I disabled that.

Comment: I'm at 70% with chrome and all tabs fully open, unity and a game started. And without suffering any lag at all. So yes this is a big difference.
And I never use the search windows tool. I have a thing for that. I just use the indexing which still works.
No need to be this agressive. Problem is solved, bye.

Answer (score 0):

Your RAM usage is so high because using RAM is *free*. Your system cannot save RAM for later. A system with 8GB can't use 6GB today so it can use 12GB tomorrow.

If you're thinking "I want my RAM free now so I can use it later", realize that that's nonsense. You can use you RAM now *and* use it later. There's no painful tradeoff to make here.

Modern operating systems go to great lengths to use as much RAM as possible unless they have no other choice. Only RAM that is being used can make your system run faster and avoid unnecessary I/O. Free RAM is no better than RAM sitting on a shelf.

Comment: I know that already. But when I can't play any games without freeze cause without anything open except the game I suffer lag and freeze cause of a 95% ram usage then it means there is a problem.
Since I disabled the service, everything is good now.

Comment: @Alfakyn1 Why did you keep your question a secret then? How could you possibly have expected a helpful answer if you didn't even tell us what your actual problem was?

Comment: My problem was a high ram usage without anything showing up. Your answer is invalid since on any normal computer, with this few things open as you can see on Task manager, it will never show a high amount used like that.
Anyway the problem is solved.

Comment: @Alfakyn1 "*Your answer is invalid since on any normal computer, with this few things open as you can see on Task manager, it will never show a high amount used like that.*" That is absolutely, 100% false. The people who design modern operating systems are not idiots, they would not intentionally design the system to waste memory if they had a choice, which they do.

Comment: there is a difference between free memory, and memory used at low priority. I don't care if my memory is used if the system is able to reallocate it. On my laptop I have no memory problem, maybe cause I have a very low number of file so search has no problem. Not the case on my desktop. That was what was explaining the man where I found the answer to my problem. Seems to be an issue on computer with a lot of files.
But here, it's like my computer wasn't able to reallocate this part of memory. Now it's used, but for usefull things.

Comment: @Alfakyn1 Maybe that's true, but your question says nothing of the kind. You question was about RAM *usage* not about inability to reallocate memory. It seems like you had some real issue and asked a question that had absolutely nothing to do with it!

Comment: Maybe I had to be clear about lags yes. But I really had a problem of ram usage and hidden. When windows use ram it tells me why, not there.
But now it's back to normal, completely smooth even with tons of demanding soft opened.